# Panel de administración firewall, fortinet

Tags: php, python, firewall

Buen día,

Actualmente la empresa donde trabajo tiene varios clientes donde se les administra el firewall con fortinet, me solicitan que desarrolle una aplicación web donde se puedan visualizar todas las gráficas de monitoreo de los clientes para no tener que abrir uno por uno y monitorear manual mente los firewall.

La aplicación web consiste en hacer un panel donde pueda visualizar todas las gráficas sin necesidad de ingresar a cada uno.

He intentado colocar las ventanas con iframe pero no funciona, no se si es posible hacer una aplicación para esta tarea o que otra alternativa puedo hacer para solucionar esta situación.

Este es el código Python para logearme en la aplicación de forma automática

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('url_aplicacion_con_el_iframe'))

usernameStr = 'usuario'
passwordStr = 'contraseña'

browser.switch_to.frame('frame_1')

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('details-button')
nextButton.click()

nextLink = browser.find_element_by_id('proceed-link')
nextLink.click()

username = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "secretkey")))

password.send_keys(passwordStr)

while True:
    time.sleep(300)
    browser.refresh()
```

Este es el iframe en html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Graficas</title>

    <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="icon">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <iframe class="embed responsive-iframe" id="frame_1" name="frame_1" src="url_fortigate"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Todo es posible, aunque para ello necesitarás hacer algo al respecto. Tu pregunta no cumple con los requisitos para ser considerada válida en este sitio. Buscas recomendaciones y/o opiniones de tu caso concreto, pero no muestras ni lo que has hecho, ni los errores que te ha dado ni lo que has investigado por tu cuenta. No somos google ni hacemos código a medida. Léete [ask] y realiza el [tour] para entender cómo realizar buenas preguntas que sean mejor aceptadas por la comunidad. Lo siento, tal como está redactada puede ser cerrada pronto y/o ser votada negativamente por todos esos motivos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.